# jQuery button in loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, twig

I'm beginning with jQuery and using it with twig/Symfony 2.
I have a little problem : when I use this in a  loop :

```
<a href="#" id="dialog_link"><button type="button" id="button_id" id-uservalue="{{user.id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
Delete
</button></a>
```

Only the 1st Button works, the other just dont. I checked the value of {{user.id}} it changes.

This is the jQuery code :

```
click : function() {
var id_user = $('#button_id').attr('id-uservalue');
```

Thanks a lot, internet friends !

Comment: __IDs in HTML must be unique__ otherwise your HTML is invalid

Comment: when using the loop for variable **i** then concatenate i with id for button so then can be unique identify then to bind the button with jquery trigger using the class on button or tag name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `id` is unique, you need to use class instead:

```
<a href="#" id="dialog_link"><button type="button" class="button_id" id-uservalue="{{user.id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
```

then you can use:

```
click : function() {
var id_user = $(this).attr('id-uservalue');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply.

I got the point about unique IDs.

When I do this, basically my design is not working anymore, and I'm not getting the id_user anymore, just undefined ones.